# Access Stage name during the build in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

Let's say we have the following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
stage name: "Cool stage"
    sh 'whoami'
stage name: "Better stage"
    def current_stage = getCurrentStageName()
    echo "CONGRATULATIONS, you are on stage: $current_stage"
```

The question is how to implement **`getCurrentStageName()`**. I know, that I can get an access to build run-time using `currentBuild.rawBuild`.
But how to get stage name from that point?

I need this for some customization in email notifications, so that I can always catch failed stage name and include it into email body.

Comment: Did you even find an answer to this? I'm looking for the same thing now

Comment: Not the real answer but workaround. You may create a sort of wrapper, which will accept stage name, write it into global variable and call `stage`

Answer (score 46):

You can now do this in a built-in manner, since Jenkins 2.3. Like so:

```
steps {
    updateGitlabCommitStatus name: STAGE_NAME, state: 'running'
    echo '${STAGE_NAME}'
}
```

For more information see: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44456

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks ( it needs to be added to their docs! )

Comment: It would be good if we can get the stageName and also stageResult

Answer (score 12):

This should work from a pipeline shared library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import hudson.model.Action;

import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepStartNode
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.LabelAction


def getStage(currentBuild){
    def build = currentBuild.getRawBuild()
    def execution = build.getExecution()
    def executionHeads = execution.getCurrentHeads()
    def stepStartNode = getStepStartNode(executionHeads)

    if(stepStartNode){
        return stepStartNode.getDisplayName()
    }
}

def getStepStartNode(List<FlowNode> flowNodes){
    def currentFlowNode = null
    def labelAction = null

    for (FlowNode flowNode: flowNodes){
        currentFlowNode = flowNode
        labelAction = false

        if (flowNode instanceof StepStartNode){
            labelAction = hasLabelAction(flowNode)
        }

        if (labelAction){
            return flowNode
        }
    }

    if (currentFlowNode == null) {
        return null
    }

    return getStepStartNode(currentFlowNode.getParents())
}

def hasLabelAction(FlowNode flowNode){
    def actions = flowNode.getActions()

    for (Action action: actions){
        if (action instanceof LabelAction) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

def call() {
    return getStage(currentBuild)
}
```

Example usage:

```
node {
    stage('Stage One'){
        echo getCurrentStage()
    }

    stage('Stage Two'){
        echo getCurrentStage()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have managed to modify your script to get a hold of the previously executed stages. Do you know of a way to get the build result of those previous stages?

Comment: Got it! http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/pipeline-rest-api/com/cloudbees/workflow/flownode/FlowNodeUtil.html#getStatus-org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.graph.FlowNode-

Comment: I made an example to get result of stages:
https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeSmaha/fdef2088f7415c60adf95d44073c3c88

Comment: Great stuff, I was able to extract the `parallel()` branches names as well.

Comment: These functions are not whitelisted for use in sandbox.

Answer (score 5):

Aleks' workaround works fine, just thought it's worth sharing the code

```
node ("docker") {
    def sendOk = {
        String stage -> slackSend color: 'good', message: stage + " completed, project - ${env.JOB_NAME}:1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
    def sendProblem = {
        String stage, error -> slackSend color: 'danger', message: stage + " did not succeed, project - ${env.JOB_NAME}:1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}, error: ${error}, Find details here: ${env.BUILD_URL}"
    }
    def exec = {
        work, stageName -> 
            stage (stageName) {
                try {
                    work.call();
                    sendOk(stageName)
                }
                catch(error) {
                    sendProblem(stageName, error)
                    throw error
                }
            }
    }
    exec({
        git credentialsId: 'github-root', url: 'https://github.com/abc'
        dir ('src') {
            git credentialsId: 'github-root', url: 'https://github.com/abc-jenkins'
        }
        sh "chmod +x *.sh"
    }, "pull")
    exec({ sh "./Jenkinsfile-clean.sh \"1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\"" }, "clean")
    exec({ sh "./Jenkinsfile-unit.sh \"1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\"" }, "unit")
    exec({ sh "./Jenkinsfile-build.sh \"1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\"" }, "build")
    exec({ sh "./Jenkinsfile-dockerize.sh \"1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\"" }, "dockerize")
    exec({ sh "./Jenkinsfile-push.sh \"1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\"" }, "push")
    exec({ sh "./Jenkinsfile-prod-like.sh \"1.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\"" }, "swarm")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, in the failure email I include a link to the *Pipeline Steps* page.  This page clearly shows green and red balls for each step, making it easy for the email recipient to figure out not just the stage, but the step that failed.

In the following example email body, the `FlowGraphTable` link links to *Pipeline Steps*:

```
def details = """<p>Job '${env.JOB_NAME}', build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} result was ${buildStatus}.
  Please scrutinize the build and take corrective action.</p>
  <p>Quick links to the details:
  <ul>
    <li><a href="${env.JOB_URL}">${env.JOB_NAME} job main page</a></li>
    <li><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">Build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} main page</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}console">Console output</a></li>
      <li><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}changes">Git changes</a></li>
      <li><a href="${env.BUILD_URL}flowGraphTable">Pipeline steps</a>.
          This page will show you which step failed, and give you access
          to the job workspace.</li>
    </ul>
  </ul></p>"""
```

This is an excerpt from my implementation of `notifyBuild()` that [BitwiseMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1637252/bitwiseman) of CloudBees presents in his article, [Sending Notifications in Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/07/18/pipline-notifications/).